# SQL ASP.NET - Convert nvarchar to int if numeric

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have an nvarchar field called [DBO] which contains either a numeric age (like 32) or other nvarchar valuesl ike Unknown or 12/10/2013

What I'm trying to achieve is to convert [DBO] to int if it's numeric. This is the code I currently have, but it's obviously not working.

```
SELECT * FROM [PeopleTable] WHERE CAST([DBO] AS INT)=32
```

It always gives me an error for [DBO]'s value not being an int. I was trying to use "CASE" but I can't see how to implement that in my command.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pull all records that are numeric only and then do your cast.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [PeopleTable] P
WHERE CAST(P.[DBO] AS INT) = 32
AND ISNUMERIC(P.[DBO]) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
[TRY_PARSE function (for SQL Server 2012 and newer)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)

And here:
[ISNUMERIC function for SQL Server 2005 and newer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM [PeopleTable] P
WHERE ISNUMERIC(P.[DBO]) = 1) AND CAST(P.[DBO] AS INT) = 32
```

Comment: It is not guaranteed that the `ISNUMERIC` is evaluated before the `CAST`

Comment: I just ran it in SSMS (SQL Server 2008) and it was evaluated first.

Comment: Observing a particular order of evaluation in a specific execution plan [doesn't constitute a guarantee](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
select 
    convert(int,[dbo])
from @t
where not ([dbo] like '%[^0-9]%')
```

If you use `ISNUMERIC`, you'll get an error if you have a decimal value in your data.

Comment: It is not guaranteed that the `WHERE` runs before the `CONVERT`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
            (
            SELECT *,
              CAST((CASE isnumeric(ColumnName) 
                      WHEN 0 THEN NULL 
                      ELSE CAST(ColumnName AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) 
                    END) AS INT) AS ColumnName1 
            FROM tablename
            ) T
WHERE ColumnName1 = yourNumber
```